# Cells with Dynamically created Heights overlap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Hi im newer to IOS dev and Im more familiar with web dev. I am running into an issue where my cells are originally rendered how I would expect them to, but after scrolling to the bottom and scrolling back to the top of my screen I noticed that the cells begin to overlap each other. After reading other stack overflow posts I am starting to think that it has to do with how I create the cells. I am attempting to create multiple labels in a cell with a for loop similar to how someone would with PHP for web dev and im wondering if this is the proper way to do it/ is this a possible cause.

```
                       for i in 0...bars.count-1 {
                            var barLabelView:UIView = UIView()
                            var barLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
                            barLabelView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: CGFloat(20 + (70 * i)), width: barView.frame.width-40, height: 50)
                            barLabelView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 27/255.0, green: 99/255.0, blue: 222/255.0, alpha: 1)
                            barLabelView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                            barLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: barLabelView.frame.width-10, height: 50)
                            barLabel.text = bars[i]
                            barLabel.textAlignment = .center
                            barLabel.numberOfLines = 0
                            barLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Chalkboard SE", size: 15)
                            barView.addSubview(barLabelView)
                            barLabelView.addSubview(barLabel)

                        }
```

Also heres how i set the height of the cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let crawlNameText = self.posts[indexPath.row].text
        let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 40, height: 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let estimatedCrawlNameFrame = NSString(string: crawlNameText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)], context: nil)


        let bars = posts[indexPath.row].bars.components(separatedBy: ", ")
        let buds = posts[indexPath.row].buds.components(separatedBy: ", ")

        if (self.posts[indexPath.row].type == "crawl") {

            var cellHeightP1 = CGFloat(estimatedCrawlNameFrame.height + 110 + 20 + 20 + 20 + 40 + 60)
            var cellHeightP2:CGFloat = CGFloat( 80 * bars.count)
            var cellHeightP3:CGFloat = CGFloat( 80 * buds.count)
            var cellHeight = cellHeightP1 + cellHeightP2 + cellHeightP3

            return cellHeight
        } else {
             return estimatedCrawlNameFrame.width + 110 + 20
        }
    }
```

and here is my cellForRowAt function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var cell = nfTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! newsFeedCell

             // Im guessing I would set the cell to nill here to clear the buttons I made

            cell.setPost(post: posts[indexPath.row])

            if (cell.profilePic != nil){
                cell.profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePic.bounds.height / 2
                cell.profilePic.clipsToBounds = true
            }

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

            print("made it here")

            print(indexPath.row)

            cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height)



            return cell
}
```

I read that I might have to clear my cell before reusing it but im not sure how to set a cell to nil. I am also wondering if using a collection view would work better but I dont know the difference between that and a tableview.
Any help or suggestions is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question but I guess Ill leave this up in case it helps anyone in the future

I added the following lines of code at my comment in the cellForRowAt function to remove the buttons

```
 for v in cell.barView.subviews{
       v.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    for v in cell.budsView.subviews{
       v.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

The issue was caused by some cells having more buttons than others so cells with less buttons were rendered with more buttons than  necessary making it appear like it was overlap but in reality it was just recycled buttons.